# Expression that factors S into Y so X evaluates to either Y or -Y?

Tags: javascript, math, expression

How do I write an expression that factors `s` (either 0 or 1) into `y` (any value) so `x` evaluates to either `y` or `-y`?

e.g.

`y` is `180`

if `s` is `0`, `x` should be `180`

if `s` is `1`, `x` should be `-180`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but perhaps `x = s === 0 ? y : -y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use powers of -1.

```
x = Math.pow(-1, s) * y;
```

Comment: There's no good reason to bring in Math.pow. Writing `x = (1 - 2*s)*y` as suggested by @lhf is better.

Comment: @RobertDodier While I agree that lhf's solution is simpler in its own right, powers of -1 should be very familiar to anyone with a math or dev background so the piece of code is instantly understandable. This solution is also more universal in case you need to expand to allowing any type of input for S.

Comment: Powers of -1 was the concept I was trying to remember. :D

Answer (score 2):

Just use linear interpolation:

```
x = (1-2*s)*y
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Learned something today. :)